# How to return a struct variable in a method

Tags: go, struct

This program does not compile. It shows that the `Env` method is not available on the struct `sample` on method `call`. I can access the `Env` variable directly in the main program, but I'm curious to know why this is not compiling.

```
package main

//Sample is a struct
type Sample struct {
    Env string
}

func main() {
    pa := &Sample{Env: "acd"}
    pa.call()
}

func (p *Sample) call() *Sample.Env {
    return &p.Env
}
```

Comment: The type of `Sample.Env` is a string. Change the signature of the `call` method accordingly: `func (p *Sample) call() *string {`

Comment: It works. Thank you.Could you please suggest how to convert the memory address returned in main to format to print its value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function types are defined by the keyword `func`, followed by an optional receiver, followed by the function name, the parameter list between parentheses (which may be empty), and the result list (which may be empty), and then the function body.

The result list (zero or more types) is the contract for what the function will return.  It can be a list of types or a list of named parameters including their types.

In your function definition for `call()`:

```
func (p *Sample) call() *Sample.Env {
```

Your result list does not meet this expectation.  `*Sample.Env` is a pointer to the `Env` property of type `Sample`, but not a type itself.

Your function returns value `&p.Env`.  If you modify your function signature so that the result list is simply the type of `&p.Env`, then your program will run.  `p.Env` is a string, therefore `&p.Env` is a pointer to a string.  `*string` is the type "pointer to a string."  Therefore if you change your function signature to this your code will work:

```
func (p *Sample) call() *string {
```

See:

1. [Function Types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types)
2. [Types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types)

### Post script

The return type of `call()` is `*string` -- that is, a pointer to a string.  So to print it you simply dereference it to a string with the asterisk:

```
env := pa.call()
fmt.Printf("Env is %s\n", *env)
```

Comment: It works. Thank you.Could you please suggest how to convert the memory address returned in main to format to print its value.